# How to check weather the indirect child exists in View or not?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

Here is my layout.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lyt_linearNative"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lyt_tp1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/vmax_iv_icon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/bee7_btn_close" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lyt_tp2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/vmax_tv_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:text="title" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/vmax_tv_desc"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:text="Description" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lyt_tp3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/vamx_tv_totalInstall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:text="total install" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/vamx_tv_price"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:text="Price" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Please consider the above layout as **template** only. There can be any number of children.

I want to check **vmax_tv_desc** is exists in **lyt_linearNative** or not.
I know we can get the direct child by using

```
 View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)parentView).getChildAt(i);
```

But I want to check for the **indirect child.**
Any help will appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: parentView.findViewById(vmax_tv_desc) is not an option? Going by index sounds wrong

Comment: @ligi Thanks mate,Ofcourse this resolve the issue, but what if I want to search without findViewById()

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @ligi I have done that by using your commented instruction. Please add that into answer so that I can accept that and it may help others also. That solved my issue but I was looking to check using index.

Comment: I have added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answer as requested in comment-section:

I would not use by index because it couples code<>layout to tight - you just can findViewById on your parent:

```
parentView.findViewById(vmax_tv_desc)
```

Comment: I got some problems, my view was not checking the hierarchy tree, only the first children.